# RADIUS Protocol - Sending more than 255 bytes in vendor-specific field

Tags: radius, protocols

I am using the RADIUS protocol to for sending some values from client to server. I am using vendor specific value pairs, and defining our own types. But the value length for Vendor-specific data is 255 and our data length is crossing it. Can any one tell me how to incorporate data with length more than 255 bytes?

Comment: What kind of data is "the dta"?

Comment: He says below they are call detail records from voip probably asterisk.

Comment: Vijay, can you describe things more fully.  What you're trying to do sounds very unusual.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control of both sides, you can have create attributes such as:

```
Vendor1 = "data"
Vendor2 = "data continued"
Vendor3 = "End Of Data"
```

If you don't have control of the far side, go ask THAT vendor how they expect the data to get through. Of at least, post the device name here so someone who has worked with it can have a clue how to help you.

Comment: data is CDR of monitored call in voip, but its crossing the 255 bytes,

Answer (score 1):

You could store the CDR somewhere say in a webserver (maybe via using a RESTful interface) Then just reference the URL for that stored CDR data in the RADIUS request.